# train own PeopleDetector() in opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, object-detection

I am new to opencv, reading the source code here: https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/modules/objdetect/src/hog.cpp
There is a methd`std::vector<float> HOGDescriptor::getDefaultPeopleDetector()` which could be used for people detection, since my pos and neg of people image size is smaller than the default people size, so I want to train my own peopleDetector, any idea or clue about how to do this? Thanks,

Comment: did you try [train_HOG.cpp](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/samples/cpp/train_HOG.cpp)

Comment: dlib also has [HOG detector](http://blog.dlib.net/2014/02/dlib-186-released-make-your-own-object.html)